# Is it possible to copy files from a Host os to a Guest OS which is running in the virtualbox ? (Not Folder sharing)

Tags: c++, c, virtual-machine

As per my understanding there is an option called Shared Folder. But I am not referring to that. Here my Guest OS is Linux and my Host OS is windows. I am using virtualbox to run the Guest OS. I need to run a simple application(C/C++) in the Linux which is running in the virtualbox.

The function syntax can be something like below

```
fun_copy(file_from_host_os,dest_path_guest_os)
{
  //Implementation
}
```

Here:

- `file_from_host_os`: The file (eg: foo.txt) present inside the windows directory.
- `dest_path_guest_os` - Location of the destination path(eg: /home/) inside the linux (running in the virtualbox)
  I am a newbie into this forum. Correct me if something is wrong from side. Thanks in advance.

PS: I added the same question in Unix stack exchange also

Edit: I don't know the feasibility of this requirement. That's why I came here. I think u folks can help me to sort out this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you want to use folder sharing?

Comment: @rustyx - As per our requirement the required file has to be copied from windows host os to linux guest os through our application. It is as part of one automation task.

Comment: You can't reach the host OS from a VM. It's the whole purpose - to isolate them. Treat it as running on another machine, ie use networking.

Comment: @rustyx I think OP wants to go the other way, which means host needs to be able to access guest's disks, not vice versa.

Comment: I am not running VirtualBox at the moment but I seem to think you can use `vboxmanage -copyto` running on the host to do that.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ok. I will check that

Comment: I'm running vbox & done a lot of research and tried a whole bunch of options, with many permutations.  Neither the file share nor; the cut-and-paste work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using the network interface?

There are plenty of tools for copying files through a network interface e.g. ftp, tftp, ssh... Linux hosts usually include some of these tools in a standard installation.

Comment: And even `rsync` for an incredibly flexible file copy/transfer tool.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This one also I will try.

Comment: @VishnuCS you may need to set the VirtualBox network interface to "bridged" mode for bi-directional transfer with the host. (I don't recall the exact details, but that seems to be something I recall having to do)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : Pointed ! I will consider that thing also.